# Installing m2e in customized Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e, eclipse-luna

I have "Visual COBOL for Eclipse", which is an eclipse version based on Luna tailored for Cobol.

Now I would like to install m2e into it. Unfortunately I am sitting behind a crazy proxy that blocks random jars from be downloaded if the user agent is not a browser (as, e.g. eclipse)

Can I download m2e as a bundle from somewhere and tell Eclipse to install it from some directory? Or is there any other way to install m2e without Eclipse trying to download jars from the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Minimally you should be able to go to the [m2e releases](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases) page and click on "Show Directory Contents" (or just add `/?d` to the end of the URL), then download the files listed there. Unfortunately that requires manually downloading everything one file at a time.

With everything downloaded I would assume that you could give it to Eclipse as a local update site, or .zip it all up as an archived update site.

I *think* you'll want one of the 1.5.x releases for Luna, although it may not matter. I'm using Luna at the moment and have 1.5.1 installed.

---

I also quickly tried the approach listed here: [How to Download Eclipse Update Site for Offline Use](http://technotes.khitrenovich.com/how-to-download-eclipse-update-site-for-offline-use/) (using `wget --recursive` on the site mentioned above), but it doesn't seem to work on the Eclipse downloads site. Also since you mention that you want to get the file directly from the browser, that approach may not even work in your case either.